# Как сделать поиск в Treeview Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, search, treeview

Как можно реализовать поиск определенных данных в Treeview? То есть надо что бы пользователь вводил данные в Entry и жал на кнопку, после чего будет происходить поиск по всем столбцам. Но главное условие - даже если небольшая часть совпадает, то эта строка выводится в Treeviee.

Comment: Не стоит полагаться на те данные, которые отображены в gui. Лучше в программе хранить список с теми данными, и по этому списку искать.

Comment: Ок, я вас понял, у меня есть БД, но как осуществить поиск по всем данным в БД??? Точнее надо чтобы поиск в БД происходил по частям слов. Например в БД есть фамилия Иванов и отдельно имя Иван, юзер вводит Иван и происходит выборка всех данных(выводит и Иванов, и Иван)?

Comment: Можно с помощью like https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_like_clause.htm

Comment: @insolor, спасибо. Буду разбираться как его использовать)